# Where to place twitter4j.properties in android project?

Tags: android, properties, twitter4j, xauth

I'm developing Twitter application with xAuth support using twitter4j jar file.

I want to place my consumer key/secret in twitter4j.properties file.

Where should I put this file in directory structure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> twitter4j.properties should be located
>   under either the default directory,
>   the root of your classpath, or the
>   WEB-INF/ directory

heres the doc.
http://www.devcomments.com/Twitter4J-now-supports-xAuth-at106339.htm

Comment: Everyone copies same sentence from doc. Well, I am totally dumb on java/android. Can you please tell me where to place in a eclipse based android project.

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse project, put in "src" directory just below.

On Android Studio (gradle-style) project, put in /app/src/main/resources/ .